# Not moved after append_row

Tags: python, gspread

```
itaworksheet = sh.worksheet("수정") # 시트 선택
itainfor = itaworksheet.get_all_records() # 리스트

for itainfo in itainfor:
    customer_Net_Contribution = itainfo['Net Contribution']
    salesperson_fixed = itainfo['확정수익']
    salesperson_expect = itainfo['예정수익']
    salesperson_code = itainfo['영업인 코드']
    salesperson_name = itainfo['영업인 이름']
    person_salesperson_name = itainfo['영업인의 영업인 이름']
    person_salesperson_code = itainfo['영업인의 영업인 코드']
    try:
        salessh = gc.open(f"{salesperson_name}_{salesperson_code}",'***********__************') # 영업인 스프레드시트 선택
        saworksheet = salessh.worksheet("ITA") # 시트 선택
        print("1")
        saworksheet.append_row([customer_Net_Contribution,'',salesperson_fixed,salesperson_expect],value_input_option="USER_ENTERED",table_range='A1')
        print("2")
        time(1)
        print("3")
        person_salessh = gc.open(f"{person_salesperson_name}_{person_salesperson_code}",'***********__************') # 영업인 스프레드시트 선택
        person_saworksheet = person_salessh.worksheet("수정") # 시트 선택
        person_saworksheet.append_row([customer_Net_Contribution,'',salesperson_fixed,salesperson_expect,'',salesperson_name],value_input_option="USER_ENTERED",table_range='A1')
        time(1)

    except:
        continue
```

I'm going to transfer the value of sheet A to sheet B and sheet C.

However, append_row does not run once and then move on.
Moving on to the next iteration.

When I ran this code, the output value was

```
1
2
1
2
1
2
1
2
```

Why isn't 3 printed?

Comment: If you remove the  blanket `try`/`except`, you will find out why it didn't work.  You should never add `try`/`except` until you know the code works, and even then you should not use a blanket `except` at all.  My guess is that `time` is undefined.

Comment: thx, time was the problem.